# How to reset a user password for Icinga-web version 1.8.4

Tags: icinga, icinga2, icingaweb2

I am running Icinga with Classic UI, but an year ago I added the Icinga-web as well.

I have tested a couple of things with it and left it behind.

Now I want to access it, but I don`t remember what were the credentials.

Is there a way to reset the password or to create a new username and password for it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you've installed Icinga Web 1.x in the first place. The sources contain a make parameter to safely reset the root user's password.

https://docs.icinga.com/latest/en/icinga-web-scratch.html

```
make icinga-reset-password
```

If you are using Debian packages, you can reconfigure the package:

```
dpkg-reconfigure icinga-web
```